# Sublime text: how to disable dual edit?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When copying a piece of text then quicking clicking somewhere else and start writing, I find myself writing both in the place I clicked *and* in place of the selected text simultaneously.

How to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you still press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key when clicking.

To disable the feature of multi edit open your `menu » preferences » key bindings - user` and add the following content.

```
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
}
```

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to work. Still get dual edit (at least I know now that it's because of CTRL + click, although it doesn't prevent the problem from happening from time to time)